# Where do i insert - google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

After searching through, Lot of people have suggest to use this `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');`
solution for hidden div, google map to render properly.As of now, only one third of map display and rest are greyed out.i have try inserting this code in each line to check. nothing work. Can some help me out.. am clueless !!
this is my js

```
$("#1").on("click",function(){
            var map;
     mapProp = { center:new google.maps.LatLng(40.73, -74.1841),
     zoom:17,
     mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

    map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

    mapProp = new google.maps.LatLng(40.73, -74.1841)

     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: mapProp,
     map: map,
     icon: 'img/marker.png',

     });

      marker.setMap(map);
     });
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load');
```

this is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/direction.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/transitions.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="css/transitions.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/apijs?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>


</head>
<body>

   <div id="Home">

<div id="picture"> <img src="img.jpg"  alt="logo"> </img></div>     

<label><div id="select">Select</label></div>
 <ul id="list"><hr>
    <li id="b1" >Mall</li><hr>
    <li id="b2" > city</li><hr>
        <li id="b3" > office</li><hr>
     <li id="b4" >Park</li><hr>
     <li id="b5" >school</li><hr>
         <li id="b6" > theater</li><hr>
    </ul>

</div>

<div id="showmap">
        <div  class="back" id="Back">Back to Names</div>
   <div id="googleMap"> </div>

</div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**solution** 
@  Andrei Beziazychnyi

**UpDate** This solve everything

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function(){
            var center = map.getCenter();
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 
            map.setCenter(center);

            });
```

After :

```
marker.setMap(map);
```

Only problem with is, my locaction is little off. had to bring down to see the marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best option I know is to use following code:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

Comment: google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function(){
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 
}); 
Above code seems to work, if i place it after marker.setMap(map); Only issue is, map comes off from the center of the screen. 
this.map.setZoom( this.map.getZoom() - 1);this.map.setZoom( this.map.getZoom() + 1);
  });

Comment: How do you use this.map.setZoom( this.map.getZoom() + 1); }); ?

Comment: either way, its still same result.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue, if you could create jsfiddle, I could dig deeper. Generally published markup is invalid, fx <label><div id="select">Select</label></div>. It could lead to some side effects.

Comment: i have solved it. Its coming out perfectly now.thank you very much for your time ..

Comment: what was the solution ?  my code is  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(mobile_map, 'idle', function() {
                var center = mobile_map.getCenter();
                google.maps.event.trigger(mobile_map, 'resize');
                mobile_map.setCenter(center);
                $log.debug("idle called");
            }); its not working.